# How can I control 2 lights with a SPDT switch?

Tags: switches, lamp

> **Note**: After some careful thought, I've opted to rather just abandon this question, see the chosen answer for more info.

I current have a 220V AC lamp with two light bulbs wired with a single on-off switch. I also have a few SPDT on-off-on switches.

What I would *like* is to have a lamp with a 3 position switch that allows me to control it as:

- both lights off
- one light on
- both lights on

The switch itself has three connections, where position A connects pins 1 and 2, while position B connects pins 2 and 3.

I did try playing around with a few circuit design webapps, I can't seem to work out how things should be connected.. Please could someone explain how I might achieve this? I'm not opposed to buying a different switch if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, just wanted to say a big thank you to the people who did propose wiring solutions for this project, I do appreciate the input from different people's perspective. Either way, the comments did prompt me to do more research, so I have definitely learnt something from this.

With that said, I'm going to stick to what I know and convert the lamp itself into a 12V LED system instead.

Answer (score 1):

If they're DC lamps and you can tolerate a small voltage drop, you could use diodes.

If they're AC, you could use a couple of relays with diodes doing the same job as for DC lamps.

But the easiest way is to use a double pole (DPDT) on-off-on switch with one pole controlling each lamp. Put power to the centre contacts on both poles, connect one lamp to one position on one pole and the other lamp to both positions on the other. No additional components are needed at all.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDUGjB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Finbarr, I just updated my question to clarify the lamp type.. It is an AC lamp, powered by the standard 220V municipal supply here in South Africa. Just to clarify, what I'm hoping for isn't possible with a SPDT switch then, correct?

Comment: Actually, ignore that last "clarification" question... If the output from switch pole A is connected to lamp 1, and the output from switch pole B is connected to both, then A and B would be connected, so either "on" position would result in both lights getting power. I think I see the need for the DPDT switch now.

Comment: Yes, as you can see from Jasen's answer it's possible to do this with a single pole switch, but not without using other components as well.

Comment: Gotcha.. Sorry to have to remove the checkmark from your answer then, but I think I'll confirm a few more things before I actually pick one and close off my question.

Comment: No problem. Bear in mind that if you're going to modify a piece of mains-powered equipment you're taking a big risk, you will void any warranty or probably home insurance and it has to be done safely. If it kills someone or burns the house down you're in big trouble :)

Comment: Yup, I am aware of the dangers involved.. There's no warranty to worry about and I'm no stranger to technology or electrical equipment, but since I normally only deal with systems running less than 24V, I thought it would be best to get some proper advice first. (:

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMW3bV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the diagram.. With regards to `D1` (which I'm assuming is just the diagram label), it looks like a `1N4007` is rated at 1000V while the circuit I'm working with is only 220V. Could you perhaps clarify which diode I would need to use there?

Comment: The diode needs to be rated above the voltage you're going to use so the 1N4007 will be fine. Without wanting to be unkind, basic questions like these suggest that this is something you should not really be considering.

Comment: Completely fair point, but I'll never learn if I don't ask.. I should've phrased that differently, basically I was just wondering if there was any need for a diode of that size here.

Comment: Quick note: I just discovered that using a diode the way proposed here will act as a rectifier, resulting in a DC circuit thereafter; unfortunately this will not work for my requirements here... I'm more familiar with straight up DC circuits, so I hadn't known about that specific point before.

Answer (score 0):

After checking with a friend who happens to be an electrical engineer, he proposed an even simpler solution for my wiring problem..

> Note: Keep in mind that my specific switch has a third position of `OFF`, where neither of the two points shown in CircuitLabs' library are connected.

Thanks for the proposed alternatives, but I believe I'll end up wiring my current project as simply as the following diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAMpNr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this way:

- `OFF` will not power either light
- `ON1` will power `LAMP1`
- `ON2` will power `LAMP2` and `LAMP1`

I do understand that if `LAMP1` blows with this configuration, neither of them will work, but I have absolutely no problem with that. So unless anybody points out any issues with this one, this is most likely how I'll wire it up.

Comment: If both lamps are truly identical **incandescent** lamps then they will be half brightness when you want both "on". If they are not incandescent or not identical then this might not work at all. If half brightness is acceptable you should have said so in your original question...it feels like you cheated the people who tried to help you.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, you literally went from asking me a question, to telling me something I didn't know, to accusing me of not giving all the relevant information in my original question *without* giving me any chance to respond first. I'm asking this question **to learn**, and I posted this as an answer **without accepting it** because I'm looking for more information. The entire point of this question is that I'm trying to learn more about something I only know the basics of. How is that cheating people out of anything?

Comment: @ZaLiTHkA - Hi, FYI, regarding: "*I posted this as an answer without accepting it because I'm looking for more information.*" For the future, that is not a good plan. Either (a) you have already decided on a solution and are *not* looking for more information, in which case it *is* an answer and should be accepted to close the topic. Or (b) it's *not* decided as the solution, but is a "request for comments", in which case it's not an answer but an *update*, and should be added to the question by editing. | Posting an update as an answer turns it into another question, and causes problems. HTH

Comment: @SamGibson next time something like that comes up, I'll word it differently. Since *that* was an answer proposed by one of my work colleagues (as I stated), not something I came up with myself.